# Can an instrument be correlated with 2 endogeneous variables in instrumental variables regression?

Tags: econometrics, instrumental-variables

Given that I have a dependent variable $Y_i$, two endogeneous variables $W_i \text{ and } X_i$ and an instrument correlated with both $W_i \text{ and } X_i$, can we still perform two stage least squares regression?

So, our regression equation is

$$Y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1 X_i + \beta_2 W_i + u_i$$

with two stage least squares procedure

$$X_i = b_0 + b_1 Z_i + \epsilon_i$$

$$ Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \hat{X}_i + \beta_2 W_i + u_i$$

where $Cov(Z_i, W_i)>0$

My guess is that $\hat{\beta}_2$ will not be unbiased and consistent. But will the estimator $\hat{\beta}_1$ be unbiased and consistent?